# Copy file to sdcard

Tags: android, copy, android-sdcard

I have an android application **which copies a file to sdcard**.

My code block is like below:

```
private void CopyXmlFile2SdCard() {
    AssetManager asstMan = getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        in = asstMan.open("platform.xml");
        File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "platform.xml");
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        CopyFile(in, out);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Copy Error", "Failed to get asset file");
    }

}
```

My copy method is:

```
private void CopyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

I am having an error "File not found" on the line :

```
out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
```

I also have given the permission required to copy to sdcard (write_external_storage).
Any suggestions would be appreciated..

Comment: and just suggestion form google http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getExternalFilesDir` is available from API LEVEL 8. Change it with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Edit.

Also, please be sure to add an sdcard in your device/emulator

Comment: are you sure your SCARD is not mounted, as external device for instance? I mean, if you got the FileNotFoundException means the directory that getExternalFilesDir returns, does not exits. And that sound a bit strange

Comment: what do you mean by that? I am using emulator to test the codes not using real device by the way ..

Comment: ah did you took care to create an sdcard for your emulator?

Comment: Well at some point I thougth that can be the problem but didnt give any chances.. How can I do that? Any links or related questions? I am pretty new to android development only 2 days actually sory for amateur questions :)

Comment: it gives you the chance when you create the Emulator. It should be a field that you can fill out with the size of the sdcard.